# What I have to do to make my app always listening to connectivity change?

Tags: android, manifest, connectivity, background-service

I want my app to do some background tasks when device is connected to internet, but "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" is deprecated, so what I have to do to make my app always listening to connectivty change even if the app is not running?

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback but ideally you should be using WorkManager

Comment: If you are using `LiveData` you can check here too: https://android.jlelse.eu/connectivitylivedata-6861b9591bcc